# How to prove $ \int_{1}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{ (1+x^3)^3 } dx$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am trying to determine whether the following improper integral is convergent or not.

$$ \int_{1}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{ (1+x^3)^3 } dx$$

I tried the following:
   $l = \lim_{x \to a} ((x-a)^k)f(x)$, if $l \in [0, \infty)$ and $k < 1$, then the integral is convergent. But I can't use it well.
Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Use a comparison test?

Comment: Perhaps the title of your question should say "convergent" not "improper".

Comment: Anyway, as @DavidMitra hinted, the inside of the integral is smaller than 1/x^6.

Comment: sorry, you are right

Comment: @DavidMitra how can I do that?

Comment: Are you confused about the range of integration? Note that the bottom limit is 1, not 0. Anyway, try to integrate $1/x^6$ in that same range. What do you get?

Comment: I think the result in that range would be 1/5 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109188/discussion-between-benjamin-wang-and-reznicencu-bogdan).

Comment: @BenjaminWang: why $x^6$ rather than $x^9$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Haha misread the exponent(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in [1,\infty)$, then $\frac{1}{(1+x^3)^3} < \frac{1}{x^6}<\frac{1}{x^2}$. So for every $n \in \Bbb N$, we have that $\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{(1+x^3)^3}<\int_{1}^n\frac{1}{x^2}$. But $\int_{1}^n\frac{1}{x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Therefore

\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{(1+x^3)^3}<1-\frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

Now taking limits we get

\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^3)^3}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{(1+x^3)^3} < \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right) = 1
\end{equation}

This shows the improper integral converges.

Comment: Why don't you just use $\frac1{(1+x^3)^3}<\frac1{x^9}$ ?